# Question about convergent and divergent series such that the sequences are convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I got a question and I can't really reach to an answer/formal proof
The question goes:
Is it possible? given 2 sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $a_n$*$b_n$$\neq$0 for every n$\in$$\mathbb N$, and $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}$$\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}$=0 and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n}$ convergent but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ divergent?
We don't know anything about nonnegativity of the sequences.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=0.$$

As, $\{\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}\}$ is convergent, it must be bounded.

So, there exists $L>0$ such that $|\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}|<L\,\forall n\in\Bbb{N}.$

Then, $|a_n|<L \cdot |b_n|.$

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n}$ is absolutely convergent, then by comparison test to see $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ is also absolutely convergent, hence convergent.

So, to produce the required counter example , we have to take $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n}$, a conditionally convergent series.

Choose, $a_n =\frac{1}{n} $ and $b_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}.$

Then, $\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}{(-1) ^n}}\to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty.$

Here, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ divergent.

But $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}}$ converges by Alternating series test.

Comment: Why downvote? Please leave a comment so that i can find my mistake. Thanks